# slowing down the page up animation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code in my `<head>` for my 'back to top button'

```
function scrolltop(){ 
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, '3000'); 
}
```

But it scrolls up too fast. I played with the numbers but nothing seems to affect it. I wish to slow it down by half what it currently is

Comment: Why are the milliseconds in quotes? _Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The default duration is 400 milliseconds. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively._ Try `...animate({scrollTop:0}, 3000)` which is 3 seconds. That is silly slow

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that was an issue, thank you! Can there be an ease applied to it through here as well?

Comment: remove single quotes around milliseconds '3000'

Comment: `$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},800,"swing");` should work as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: thanks, works great!